# Dll not found exception : AkSoundEngine

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am working on `unity 2018.3.7f1` for Android.

The game was working fine as far as we were sending apks on android but now we are giving 64-bit support and making android app bundles from unity.

The problem I'm facing is when a user downloads the game from the play store it is stuck after one scene. I have checked the logs and it says `dll` not found exception: Unable to load `dll 'AkSoundEngine'`: The specified module could not be found.

I am using `wwise` for sounds in the project.

Comment: Did you put it in the plugins area?

Comment: No its in Assets/Wwise/Deployment folder which is be default path for wwise.

Comment: Well thats why it doesnt know to copy the dll on deployment

Comment: Should i place wwise folder in Plugins folder?

Comment: No it should really be just the dll